# How do you pass a variable to a Zend 3 Fieldset?

Tags: zend-framework3

How do you pass a variable to a Zend 3 Fieldset?

I have a dropdown list which I am populating using a database table however I need the product id from the get request to only show options available for that product?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by requesting the 'router' and 'request' object from the fildset factory to get the param from the url and then passed it into the fildset. Here is the code;

```html
namespace Catalog\Form\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Catalog\Form\ProductBrandingOptionPricesFieldset;

class ProductBrandingOptionPricesFieldsetFactory implements FactoryInterface
{    
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        
        $router = $container->get('router');
        $request = $container->get('request');
        
        // Get the router match
        $productId = $router->match($request)->getParam("id");

        // Instantiate the controller and inject dependencies
        return new ProductBrandingOptionPricesFieldset($entityManager,$productId);
    }

}
```